# Is there any naturally occurring downward force that exists on Earth other than gravity?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, newtonian-gravity, free-body-diagram

For a project, I was wondering whether or not it is possible to increase the net downwards force acting on an object so that you are able to manipulate its weight.

Comment: That's a bit of a thin question. Haven't you _thought_ of any obvious candidates for such a force? And what properties does the force need, apart from pointing downwards?

Comment: Downwards isn’t an absolute thing. It doesn’t make sense to ask. If your question if there exist other attractive forces, then yes.

Comment: So far, I've seen that it is possible to create a magnetic force to point downwards with the Hall effect. However, I was wondering if there was any simpler alternative.

Comment: What about a magnetic force pulling downwards just by having a magnet placed in the ground? Or a big suction pump that pulls in everything. What exactly is the criteria here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is commonly done, as in the following examples.

By pulling air out from under a race car using a large powered fan, the downward force pushing its tires into the pavement can be dramatically increased and its high-speed cornering ability greatly enhanced.

by whirling an object around rapidly in a circle, the apparent weight due to gravity of the object can be increased by anywhere from 10X to several million times.

Comment: Is it possible that you can direct me to a link that explains in further detail your second example and how the physics work behind this, what the phenomenon is, etc.

Comment: certainly, it is called a centrifuge and is used in the biological sciences to separate components of cells in solution by whirling them around in test tubes at tremendous speed. the force generated by that circular motion is the *centrifugal force* and a full treatment of it can be found on wikipedia.

Answer (score 0):

In everyday life there are other forces that can act on a body, electric , magnetic, and centrifugal and centripetal....

The simplest for a project imo is the electric, by using [triboelectric effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triboelectric_effect) to charge a pith ball sphere. [Here is a demonstration](http://youtube.com/watch?v=aeiqw81kGio) of the forces produced by nearing a  charged rod to a charged pith ball.

If you  were measuring the weight of the ball and brought the charged rod up directly underneath , it would modify the weight.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are great, but I think what would really satisfy you is to consider a free-body diagram in an accelerating elevator.

Consider you take the weight of an object on the ground. The object is pulled to Earth with force $-mg$ (according to my one-dimensional sign convention) so the scale reads $N = mg$ since the forces must sum to $0$.

If you are in an elevator accelerating upwards, then your forces must net to greater than $0$. The mass and weight of the object cannot change, so the the scale will push up with force $N>mg$.

You can also achieve this *illusion* of increased weight by pushing down on the scale while the object is being weighed.